# Summing values in a dictionary based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, iteration, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to sum values between multiple dictionaries, for example:

```
oneDic = {'A': 3, 'B': 0, 'C':1, 'D': 1, 'E': 2}
otherDic = {'A': 9, 'D': 1, 'E': 15}
```

I want to sum up the values of in `oneDic` *if* they are found in `otherDic` *and if* the corresponding value in `otherDic` is less than a specific value

```
oneDic = {'A': 3, 'B': 0, 'C':1, 'D': 1, 'E': 2}
otherDic = {'A': 9, 'D': 1, 'E': 15}
value = 12
test = sum(oneDic[value] for key, value in oneDic.items() if count in otherTest[count] < value
return (test)
```

I would expect a value of 4, because `C` is not found in `otherDic` and the value of `E` in `otherDic` is not less than `value`

But when I run this code I get a lovely key error, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet works. I do not know what the `count` variable in your code is:

```
oneDic = {'A': 3, 'B': 0, 'C':1, 'D': 1, 'E': 2}
otherDic = {'A': 9, 'D': 1, 'E': 15}

value = 12
test = sum(j for i,j in oneDic.items() if (i in otherDic) and (otherDic[i] < value))
print(test)
```

[Link to working code](http://repl.it/jpn)

Comment: I like this one better than the other answer because both conditions being tested for explicit.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
sum(v for k, v in oneDic.items() if otherDic.get(k, value) < value)
```

Here we iterative over the `k, v` pairs of oneDic and only include them if the return from `otherDic.get(k, value)` is `< value`.  `dict.get` takes two arguments, the second being optional.  If the key is not found, the default value is used.  Here we set the default value to be `value` so that missing keys from `otherDic` are not included.

By the way, the reason you get the `KeyError` is because you are trying to access `B and C` at some point in the iteration by doing `otherDic['B']` and `otherDic['C']` and that is a `KeyError`.  However, using `.get` as in `otherDic.get('B')` will return the default of `None` since you did not supply a default - but it will not have a `KeyError`